# Inaccurate description of [Good|Nice|Great] [Question|Answer] badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

For each the description is:

> Answer voted up N times

Where `N` is a threshold for the badge. In reality, however, the badge is achieved when `upvotes - downvotes` passes that threshold. Perhaps a better wording would be:

> Answer upvotes exceeds downvotes by N

Along those lines, what about [related badges for uncontested answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49192)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, changed from

> voted up (n) times

to

> score of (n) or more

Answer (score 2):

I would rather say it should be somethign like `Answer has a net vote count of N`. But yes, the current wording is confusing and there have been questions made about it before "I'm suppose to have this badge for my +10/-2 answer!"