# Badge request: [Solid|Authoritative|Unquestioned] [Question|Answer] badge

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

Along the lines of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49189), what about badges for answers that cross thresholds with no downvotes? Something along the lines of:

- **Solid Answer** - Bronze - Answer upvoted 10 times with no downvotes
- **Authoritative/Unanimous Answer** - Silver - Answer upvoted 20 times with no downvotes
- **Undisputed/Unquestioned Answer** - Gold - Answer upvoted 30 times with no downvotes

(All of the above applies for the related question badges, too- I want my Unquestioned Question badge!)

Comment: *Answer upvoted x times with no downvotes*: I think it's a shame a single wrong/misleaded/retaliory downvote could ruin your badge then...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

People upvote a *lot* more often than they downvote.  These badges would be so prevalent as to become meaningless.  For example, every one of my Nice Answer posts would immediately become Solid Answer posts as well.  I don't think this badge is different enough from the current ones to justify it.

Comment: What about raising the thresholds, then? There is a place for singling out questions/answers that are totally agreeable.

Comment: I argue that it does not matter what the thresholds are.  The ratio of downvotes to upvotes is so small, 99% of questions that have Nice Answer would also have Solid Answer, regardless of the thresholds.  The badges just are not different enough.

Answer (score 1):

If you give good answers, there are already plenty of badges available.

To put it another way before someone else does: do you *really* want to give me hundreds more badges? Obviously I do get downvotes, but I suspect 90% of my answers don't have any, and I have 1170 nice answer badges... do you want to give me another 1000 bronze badges in one fell swoop?

Comment: maybe @fbrereto *really* likes you!